# how to import javascript class into electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a file, f1.js, that i will like to use in another f2.js.

f1.js

```
  import firebase from 'firebase';

  const config = {

    apiKey: "your api key here",
    authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
  
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  export const firebase_auth = firebase.auth;
  export const firebase_db = firebase.database();
  export const firebase_functions = firebase.functions()
```

f2.js

```
import { firebase_auth,firebase_functions,firebase_db } from "../services/f1";

module.exports = class authManager {

   constructor(data) {

   }
}
```

I want to use the authManager class from f2.js in an electron render window f3.html. Here is the f3.html file and my attempt to call the authManager

f3.html

```js
<script>
        const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
        const loadBalancer = require('electron-load-balancer');
        const path = require('path');
        // const { helper } = require('../utils/postProcessor.js');
        const log = require('electron-log');
    
        // 1. Tell PythonShell which script to run for this background task
        let pyshell = new PythonShell(path.join(__dirname, '/../scripts/process1.py'), {
            pythonPath: 'python3',
        });
        log.info('Python spawned:', pyshell && pyshell.command);
    
        PROCESS_NAME = 'process 1';
        
        
           loadBalancer.job(
            ipcRenderer,
            PROCESS_NAME,
            () => {
            
            
            pyshell.on(
                    'message',
                       function (results) {
                   
                        try {
                            const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(results);
                            const barcode = parsedJSON["result"]
                            const serial = parsedJSON["serial"]
                            


                            const signin = new authManager(serial)
                            const auth_status = signin.authenticate()
                            



                              
                        } catch (error) {
                            log.error(error);
                        }
                    });
            },
            () => {
                // 6. Cleanup PythonShell when cleanup callback called
                pyshell.terminate();
            },
        );
```

I tried calling the authManager using different methods such as

```
 const authManager = require('/../helpers/f2.js')
```

none of them seem to work.

What is the proper way to call the authManager in f3.html

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of the problem, but the imports in the auth manager seem wrong to me. if you export something with the name `db` you have to import it with the same name...so your import statement should look more like this: `import { auth, db } from '../services/f1`;` I left out the firebase_funcitons import because I don't know where that is coming from. You can't import something that isn't exportet.

Comment: @MrCodingB yes you are right, that was a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: Your location for `authManager` is wrong. There should be `.` before the first forward slash to properly reference it using relative path.